# <div> expand on click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been surfing the internet to find the answer about how to make a div go down, when clicked on it. But i have no got it. By The way, I havent got a code. I will be thankfull, if someone could give me an explanation about it.

Comment: this question doesn't show much evidence of research. The topic you're looking for is 'accordion' and a common way to implement it is with JQuery, see the guide here https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: *«how to make a div go down»*, you mean to show it? If it isn't already shown, how could you click on it? Post some code about what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not really obvious but I will try to answer it.

Usually you insert divs inside another div and you set that class or element to hidden in css. Then, when the user clicks on the div, you change the css property using JS or Jquery and you set it to visible.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    .hidden {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .show {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .blue {
        background: blue;
        color:white;
        heigth:400px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256 hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<div id="parent" class="blue">
Click on the div
    <div id="content" class="hidden">
      .... Some content inside that is first hidden then showed when user 
      clicks
    </div>
<div>

<script>

$('#parent').on('click', function () {
    $(this).children(':first').toggleClass('show');

});

</script>
```

Comment: You got my question. I got your idea. But code is'nt working.

Comment: I've updated my answer will all the code necessary and it should work. Please have a look at the updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood a question, then I will try to help.

Css

```
#my_div {
    height: 15px;
    background: #ccc;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_div').click(function() {
        $(this).css('height', '100px'); 
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div id="my_div">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</div>
```